# How can I mount a CIFS share from an MS-DOS computer

Tags: mount, samba, smb, cifs

I am using 2 MS-DOS computers + 1 Windows 7 computer + 1 Raspberry Pi are connected to Cisco router through ethernet. I am easily able to map DOS shared folder in wWindows computer, `\\DOSMCJB\DAT` command will map a drive in Windows without any problem.

Here are some options I have tried to mount shared folder on a Raspberry Pi

To get the ping of NetBIOS name I have changing `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

Change that line to:

```
hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns wins mdns4
```

Installed

```
sudo apt-get install winbind libnss-winbind
```

Then I was able to ping by NetBIOS name.

I have added few parameters in /etc/samba/smb.conf file, 
edited:

```
; interfaces = lo eth0
; bind interfaces only = no
```

```
# Global parameters
[global]
    client max protocol = NT1
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    logging = file
    map to guest = Bad User
    max log size = 1000
    name resolve order = lmhosts bcast host wins
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    server role = standalone server
    unix password sync = Yes
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    wins support = Yes
    idmap config * : backend = tdb


[homes]
    browseable = No
    comment = Home Directories
    create mask = 0700
    directory mask = 0700
    valid users = %S


[printers]
    browseable = No
    comment = All Printers
    create mask = 0700
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = Yes


[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers
```

`smbtree` command shows

```
WORKGROUP
    \\RASPBERRYPI           Samba 4.9.5-Debian
        \\RASPBERRYPI\IPC$              IPC Service (Samba 4.9.5-Debian)
        \\RASPBERRYPI\print$            Printer Drivers
    \\WINDOWSPC             
    \\DOSMCJA               MS-DOS Peer Server 
    \\DOSMCJB               MS-DOS Peer Server
```

`smbclient -L DOSMCJB` command shows

```
Enter WORKGROUP\pi's password: 
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
```

`nslookup DOSMCJB` command shows

```
Server:     192.168.0.1
Address:    192.168.0.1#53

** server can't find DOSMCJB: NXDOMAIN
```

In below mount command I am getting `mount error(104): connection reset by peer`:

```
sudo -i mount -t cifs -o rw,netbiosname=DOSMCJA,user=username,guest,vers=1.0 //DOSMCJA/DAT /home/pi/myDOSMA/DOSMA
```

I have changed `vers=3.0` I get `mount error(112): Host is down`:

```
sudo -i mount -t cifs -o rw,netbiosname=DOSMCJA,user=username,guest,vers=1.0 //DOSMCJA/DAT /home/pi/myDOSMA/DOSMA
```

I have disabled the `ufw` status shows as inactive

```
sudo ufw disable
```

`nmap DOSMCJA` command gives me.

```
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-03-17 22:55 IST
Nmap scan report for DOSMCJB (10.9.12.20)
Host is up (1.7s latency).
Not shown: 983 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
25/tcp   closed smtp
110/tcp  closed pop3
111/tcp  closed rpcbind
113/tcp  closed ident
135/tcp  closed msrpc
139/tcp  open   netbios-ssn
143/tcp  closed imap
199/tcp  closed smux
256/tcp  closed fw1-secureremote
995/tcp  closed pop3s
1025/tcp closed NFS-or-IIS
1720/tcp closed h323q931
1723/tcp closed pptp
3306/tcp closed mysql
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server
6123/tcp closed backup-express
8080/tcp closed http-proxy

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 281.58 seconds
```

After installing winbind 139 port was open.

Please help me to mount the share from MS-DOS peer server. If any additional details required please let me know.

Comment: What messages do you get from the cifs module in `dmesg`? Why do you think vers=3 would work? Why are you configuring _server_ parameters if the computer is supposed to be acting as _client_?

Comment: Server was configured long back, i don't have permission to modify.                               [ 3734.752432] FS-Cache: Netfs 'cifs' registered for caching
[ 3734.752668] Key type cifs.spnego registered
[ 3734.752682] Key type cifs.idmap registered
[ 3734.761329] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[ 3734.761337] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -111
[ 8835.242134] CIFS VFS: Server DOSMCJA has not responded in 180 seconds. Reconnecting...
[ 8835.242350] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -112

Comment: Try to change the mount option `vers=1.0` to `vers=2.0`. And what is "an MS-DOS computer"?

Comment: I have tried with vers=1.0, vers=2.0, vers=2.1 and Vers=3.0, nothing works. It's a MS-DOS peer server. Connected to machines with RS 235 to collect machine data, and also system is SCADA storage system.

Comment: Those messages look like you're not connecting to your cifs server. Can you temporarily turn off the firewall and try again? You're generally going to need ports 135-139, and 445 as well. You'll also want to specify a user on the server like `smbclient //host/share -U DOMAIN\\myuser`. If your server is up to date: only try with vers=2.0+. SMBv1 is disabled on many machines by default or through updates now. Very old machines may only support v1.

Comment: my UFW is disabled, status shows as inactive. I am not able to open the ports. only port 139 is open after installing winbind. I am assuming no firewall is running, is there any command to check the firewall status?. How can i open the ports from terminal?, please help me with the terminal command.

Comment: I have mapped the DOS shared folder in windows 7 with out any problem. //DOSMCJA/DAT is the path to map. I am facing lot of difficult in Linux. smbclient -L DOSMCJA gives me error nt_status_connection_refused.

Comment: Do you mean a FreeDOS server? If it is, please comment on this [article](https://www.lazybrowndog.net/freedos/virtualbox/?page_id=350).

Comment: Yes, it similar. MS-DOS Peer Server.

Comment: What command should i use to mount the shared folder of FreeDOS in linux.? Please help me with terminal command.

Comment: See my above [link](https://www.lazybrowndog.net/freedos/virtualbox/?page_id=350).

Comment: I have gone through the link and commented on the article. The author explained about SHARE AN UBUNTU DIRECTORY WITH FREEDOS, I am looking for opposite (SHARE AN FREEDOS DIRECTORY WITH UBUNTU).

Comment: The article is "Share a FreeDOS directory with Windows". In Ubuntu you will see this share if SAMBA is installed (it should be).

Comment: Thank you for your support, I have installed samba, I was not able to find equivalent of "net use", I tried net user, net share, net rap share, net share migrate all. I was not able to find the exact windows replacement of net use in samba. By using "net lookup NetBIOS name" would give me exact DOS computer ip address. Please can you help me with exact net. Command option?

Comment: To access a Windows shared folder from Linux, for example using Konqueror, click on *Network Folders > Samba Shares > Windows Home workgroup > Workgroup >  computer* and enter username and password. To mount the share and for more info see [this article](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001636.htm).

Comment: Has this information helped you?

Answer (score 1):

In FreeDOS, a share is defined using the commands:

```
net start server
NET SHARE sharename=local path
```

For example, the following command will create a share called `myshare`
on the the directory `C:\SHARE`:

```
net share myshare=C:\SHARE
```

You can see the share `myshare` over the network and even mount it locally.

for example using Konqueror, click on
*Network Folders > Samba Shares > Windows Home workgroup > Workgroup > computer*
and enter username and password.

To mount the share, use the Samba client:

```
smbclient //ComputerName/ShareName -U Username
```

References (even if the contents don't all apply here):

- [Share a FreeDOS directory with Windows](https://www.lazybrowndog.net/freedos/virtualbox/?page_id=350)
- [How to share files between a Linux and Windows computer](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001636.htm)

Comment: While using "smbclient //DOSMCJA/DAT -U DOSMCJA" unable to initialize messaging context Protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT

Comment: Can you see the share in the file manager (Konqueror/Nautilus)?

Comment: I am running on raspberry pi, I have installed Nautilus, tried "smb://DOSCMJA/DAT" it is keep on showing busy icon, without any error message.

Comment: I am trying to remove and reinstall samba cifs-client smbclient samba-common samba-common-tools winbind. I feel something wrong with the smbclient version 3.9.5, Few people solved there problem by degrading version. Your suggestions appreciated.